# Change Window location dynamically by #id - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I have url like this -

```
http://test.com/simple-post#5
```

Here #5 will change dynamically.
My html divs are many like

```
<div id=1> Div 1 </div>
<div id=2> Div 2 </div>
....
<div id=5> This </div>
```

So, **when page loads windows location will go that div by id. How can I do that** using Jquery/Javscript?

I know in jquery I can redirect window location by `window.location`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.location = "#";
});
```

Please tell me if there is other efficient way to do this.

Comment: you want one line code?

Comment: After load the page retrieve the #id and change window location. One line or how you can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go actually with your current code without any script.

If that is not working and you want to do it with script, you can do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var afterhash = location.hash.substr(1);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#'+afterhash).position().top}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: This like a charm.. Thanks @Suresh

Comment: @ManiruzzamanAkash accepting the answer goes a long way in 1) Appreciating the time taken to give an answer 2) Making this information available for other people looking for a solution to this. Cheers :)